# Find the parametric equation of a circumference in a non traditional reference frame

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems, curves, parametric

I know that the parametric equation of a circumference center in (0,0) is:

$y=\sin(\alpha)*r, x = \cos(\alpha)*r$.

I try to write the equation of the same circumference with respect to the reference frame in the figure ($x',y'$) -- center of the frame $y_C=-0.6, \,x_C=0$.

[image]

I try in a lot of ways but I can't find an answer.

How can I write it?

I think that it should be something like:

$x=f_1(\theta,r)*\cos(\theta), y=f_2(\theta,r)*\sin(\theta)$

Comment: maybe if you make $A$ and $G$ coincident, you will see the relation of $\cos \theta$ with $\cos \alpha$ and $\sin \theta $ with $\sin \alpha$

Comment: @GCab I  make A and G coincident but I can't find the relation between the angles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Cartesian system $(x',y')$, the equation of the circle is $$x'=r\cos\alpha\\y'=0.6+r\sin\alpha$$
From here $$x'^2+(y'-0.6)^2=r^2$$
Using $$\tan\theta=\frac{y'}{x'}$$
We can write $$y'=x'\tan\theta$$
Therefore $$x'^2+(x'\tan\theta-0.6)^2=r^2$$
This is a quadratic. Choose the positive solution at $\theta=0$
$$x'^2(1+\tan^2\theta)-1.2x'\tan\theta+0.36-r^2=0\\
1+\tan^2\theta=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}\\
x'_{1,2}=\frac{1.2\tan\theta\pm\sqrt{1.44\tan^2\theta-4\frac1{\cos^2\theta}(0.36-r^2)}}{\frac2{\cos^2\theta}}$$
You can simplify this further ( I just choose the solution with `+`):
$$x'=\cos\theta\frac{\cos\theta}2\left(1.2\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}+\frac{2}{\cos\theta}\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\theta}4(1.44\tan^2\theta+\frac{4}{\cos^2\theta}(r^2-0.36))}\right)\\=\cos\theta(0.6\sin\theta+\sqrt{r^2-0.36\cos^2\theta})$$
Similarly, you can find out $y'$. You should check if I did not make some silly mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I find that the final equations are : $x' = cos(\theta) (y_c * sin(\theta) + \sqrt{ (y_c^2 * (sin(\theta)^2 - 1 ) + r^2)})$ $y' = sin(\theta)^2 * y_c + sin(\theta) * \sqrt{y_c^2 * sin(\theta)^2 - (y_c^2 - r^2)}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that in $x'y'$ this is
$$(x')^2+(y'-0.6)^2=r^2$$
Then 
$x'=r\cos\theta$, and $y'=0 .6+r\sin\theta$

Comment: I don't think it's correct.

Comment: @Ugo Mela why? You can show a counterxample...

Comment: This could be correct if you put as $sin$ and $cos$ arguments $\alpha$, not $\theta$, but as I say in the question I want the $x = f(\theta, r)$ not $\alpha$ ...

Comment: @Ugo Mela I think that $\tetha$ not depent, of $\alpha$ if $0\leq\theta \leq2\pi$ you get the same circle in $x'y'$, or you show a counterxample...

Answer (score 0):

From the sketch (allow me to change your symbology)
[image: Cerchio_eccentrico_1]

it is clear that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  R\cos \theta  = r\cos \alpha  \hfill \cr 
  R\sin \theta  = s + r\sin \alpha  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Squaring each line , summing, and replacing $\alpha$ with $\theta$
$$
\eqalign{
  & R^{2}  = r^{2} \cos ^{2} \alpha  + \left( {s + r\sin \alpha } \right)^{2}  =   \cr 
  &  = r^{2}  + s^{2}  + 2sr\sin \alpha  = r^{2}  + s^{2}  + 2s\left( {R\sin \theta  - s} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad R^{2}  - 2s\sin \theta R - \left( {r^{2}  - s^{2} } \right) = 0  \cr 
  & R = s\sin \theta  \pm \sqrt {s^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta  + r^{2}  - s^{2} } \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad R = s\sin \theta  + \sqrt {r^{2}  - s^{2} \cos ^{2} \theta }  \cr} 
$$

and the last is the polar equation of the excentric circle.